# Can I expand Google Image seach screen by scrolling down programatically?

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-image-search

I try to scrap some images from Google but this scroll down expansion of the site limits me to download only a certain amount of image. Is there any way to mimic that by a python code? For instance Machanize might be in use in such case if possible.

So I need to simulate scroll down expansion of Google Image search to increase the number of returned results and get image urls to scrap out.

Comment: i know `selenium` can scroll pages easily

Comment: Have you considered using the [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) to scrape images searched with Google?

Comment: API is also limited. I need to get a huge bundle for my thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably will get you banned pretty quickly, but I'm not sure. This requires BeautifulSoup and requests.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.session()
s.headers.update({"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"})

URL = "https://www.google.dk/search"
images = []

def get_images(query, start):
    screen_width = 1920
    screen_height = 1080
    params = {
        "q": query,
        "sa": "X",
        "biw": screen_width,
        "bih": screen_height,
        "tbm": "isch",
        "ijn": start/100,
        "start": start,
        #"ei": "" - This seems like a unique ID, you might want to use it to avoid getting banned. But you probably still are.
    }

    request = s.get(URL, params=params)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(request.text)

    for img in bs.findAll("div", {"class": "rg_di"}):
        images.append(img.find("img").attrs['data-src'])


#Will get 400 images.
for x in range(0, 5):
    get_images("cats", x*100)

for x in images:
    print x
```

Comment: @alexmulo - Google doesn't like you scraping their services, as they have API endpoints for most of them. Google tend to hit you with a captcha on their search engine if you do queries too fast, or too systematically. Also, there might be slight differences in the way I wrote the script, and the way it is intended to be done, this can be spotted by google.